# Applying fixed point theorem when function is implicit

Tags: game-theory, nonlinear-system, banach-fixed-point

I have a system of two equations(non linear).
$\phi_1(x_1,x_2)=0$ and $\phi_2(x_1,x_2)=0$. ($x_1,x_2 \in R)$ Substitution is not possible since both the equations are highly non linear. I was looking for a way to prove that a solution exists.(Numerical and graphical analysis seem to suggest that a solution exist).But i was unable to find any theorem that I can apply for proving an existence of solution. I read that the Banach fixed point theorem is sometimes used to show that solution will exist. But i am unable to see how I can use it since my function is defined implicitly.
Here is how i went about it.

Defining $B_1(x_2)$ and $B_2(x_1)$ as the best response function, the problem becomes equivalent to finding the an $x^*$ such that $(B_1(x^*_2),B_2(x^*_1))-(x^*_1,x^*_2)=0$.I tried to move forward by trying to prove that the best response functions are concave. Hence there would $\exists \lambda \in(0,1)$ such that ||B(y)-B(x)||<$\lambda||y-x||$ for all y and x $\in R^2$.
I am not sure if this is a valid approach. Is there any other result that i can use to prove the existence of a solution for such a non linear system.

For reference ,

Comment: You may employ the Brouwer fixed point theorem. In terms of showing existence it is more versatile than the Banach fixed point theorem. Here is a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: @humanStampedist So i can prove that that the best response functions are bounded subset of X, then i can use the brouwer fixed point theorem to claim that there is an equilibrium.  I think that will work for me. Thanks